# Questions about method and class relationship and a switch statement

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

Graduated with cs degree, but had a non programming job for a year so i'm trying to get back into it. Sorry if this is obvious, but there's two main questions about this code.

In case 1, I wanted it to go back to the start of the code and look for another input again. SO i called readinput again at the end of case 1. It ignores this and just continues on printing out case

Second, I understand in object oriented programming an instance of a class must exist for it to be called. I created this instance and called it help. Why is it when i use my readInput method, i don't just call help, but instead I have to call Help help?

```
package practice;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Help {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {// needed for a keyboard input
        Help help = new Help();
        System.out.println("Help on:");
        System.out.println(" 1. if");
        System.out.println(" 2. switch");
        System.out.println("Choose one:");

        readInput(help);

    }

    public static void readInput(Help help) throws IOException {
        char choice = (char) System.in.read();
        switch (choice) {
            case '1':
                System.out.println("The if:\n");
                System.out.println(" if(conditional) statement;");
                System.out.println(" else statement;");
                readInput(help);
                // break;

            case '2':
                System.out.println("The switch:\n");
                System.out.println("switch (expression) {");
                System.out.println("  case constant:");
                System.out.println("    statement sequence");
                System.out.println("    break;");
                System.out.println("  //...");
                System.out.println("}");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Selection not found.");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think main tag `java` is missing

Comment: i added the java tag, is there a reason my post is downvoted? I'm new to stack overflow, used it once a few years ago.

Comment: It's probably downvoted because your question was badly formatted, and your code was badly indented.

Comment: K thanks, I will have work on that. Any advice on formatting questions better?

Comment: Yes. Add spacing where spacing is needed. Use your IDE to properly indent the code (in mine, you just press Cmd-Alt-L, and the whole file id indented).

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't ignore it. Type <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you'll see that readInput() is executed several times. If you type <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, then the second character is a line break, and you just fall into the default case of your switch statement.
2. `help` is the name of the variable (argument, in that case). `Help` is the type of the argument. When you define a method `readInput(Help help)`, you're saying that this method needs one argument of type `Help`, that you choose to name `help`.

Comment: What do you mean by the second character is a line break. There is a break on the next line. But how come when read input, help is used again, it does not look for another keyboard input. Perhaps some type of "pause" needs to be added? I would like it to look for another input. So if I hit 1. It displays case one, but then waits for another input.

Comment: Open a text editor. Type 1, then Enter, then 1. The second 1 is on a separate line, right. That means that between the first 1 and the second 1, there is a character: a line break. So, the second call to System.in.read() returns this character. This character is not 1 nor 2, so the default case of your switch statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your break statement in the first case is commented, I think this the reason why the second block is executed.

About your second question, you have been able to call method readInput method without needing to call it from a Help instance because you declared it as a static method, a static method can always be called from any other method (regardless if its instance method or static, like main method).

Comment: No. System.in.read() blocks. It returns -1 if System.in is closed.